# Realtek NIC running at 100Mb/s rather than 1000Mb/s

Tags: network-adapter, speed

My Realtek NIC in my Windows Home Server (essentially w2k3) box refuses to run at 1000Mb/s even if I change the driver settings from Auto Negotion to 1000Mb/s full duplex. I've installed the latest driver and tried changing the speed setting but I'm having no luck. Not sure what to try next. Any ideas?

I have a Netgear GS605 v2 Switch supports 10/100/1000 D Link DIR 655 router.

All my machines bar one/2 have 1000Mb/s NICs (Old laptop/Xbox being the exceptions)

The reason I noticed the problem was because I was copying files between two machines and maxing one NIC out and only seeing 10% on the other machine. I do have a fairly lengthy cable between the switch and the router (maybe 20m) could that be the issue?

Comment: Check if your Switch/Router/Hub supports 1000Mbps and that your cables are 5E certified.

Comment: Also, check the specs on the Realtek NIC itself. As of 2017, Hewlett-Packard is shipping (ostensibly) high-end laptops (i.e. "Envy") with only a 10/100 chip (...and also burying this fact in the specs to a suspicious degree). The sad solution for this gyp is to abandon the Realtek and stick a Gigabit adapter/dongle in the USB 3.0 port.

Comment: I have the same problems, but they started after my router was replaced for a new one (SAME model!). Now, every time my windows 10 resumes from sleep, the LAN handshakes at 100Mbps! Cable is the SAME (CAT 5E), no problems for years with old equipment... If i unplug and plug it again, bingo, 1Gbps! Still debugging!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have already noted you need to be connected to a gigabit switch and, of course, there will need to be other gigabit enabled computers connected to that switch to get any practical benefit.

Note that if you are using a garden variety router/modem/switch it is almost certainly going to only be 100Mbit.

The other thing to be wary of is the cables being used. Yesterday I tracked down a similar problem in my own network where one of the computers would only connect at a slow speed. It turned out to be a dodgy Ethernet cable. You will need cables marked as Cat5E or, preferably, Cat6.

Comment: It was the cables! I finally found time to check all the cables between the two machines and switched out a couple of unarked cheapy cables for some Cat 5e ones and boom 1GBs. I'mamazed I was always very skeptical that cables made a difference. Thanks!

Comment: I was skeptical when I read the solution but I tried it and replacing the cable also solved my problem and bumped speed on one of my computers from 100 to 1000 MBPS. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are definately sure you're using a gigabit switch, you need to ensure that all the devices on the network (including the switch) are capable of auto negotiation. Otherwise, the devices will not show and operate correct speeds, and you'll have what's known as a [Duplex Mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplex_mismatch).

Other useful links on the topic:

- [Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet)
- [Auto Negotiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonegotiation)

Answer (score 1):

Where do you plug the ethernet cable into?
Is it a switch/router that only supports 100Mbit/s? If yes, then that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same Problems, have an Internet connection of 500 Mbits, but recived only 100 Mbits on my Laptop and so i tried and checked everything, but seemed nothnig really worked.
But then i found the solution:

Got to your Device-Manager ---> Networkadapter ---> search for your **NIC** / Network Interface Card (for examplemine was a Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller) ---> Select it an go to Properties ---> go to section Advanced ---> And now make sure:

- Look for Option "Autom. deactivate Gigabit" and set it to **not avaiable**!
- Speed and Duplex is set to **1.0 Gbps Full Duplex**( if 1.0 Gbps Full Duplex is not displayed then your NIC is not designed for an Duplex of more than 100 Mbps)
- The cable should be **Cat 5e or better**

The first one fixed it for me

Answer (score -1):

I had a problem with the wrong/broken cable. The cable was broken. It was a cat 5e but did register as 100 Mbps only. After switching the cable to cat 6 my pc registered the speed to 1 Gpbs.