# Realtek gbe family controller throttled at 100mbps

Tags: networking, network-adapter, gigabit-ethernet

I recently sent my laptop to service and I believe they changed the motherboard. Before that I could get 1000mbps, but now the connection is stuck at 100mbps as you can see in the screenshot:

[image: Adapter properties]

The router and the cable remained the same. I tried 2 different versions of drivers, including the last one on the realtek website. I performed a clean install of the windows, the speed won't budge.

EDIT: The laptop is an ASUS GL752VW

I know that most people think it's the cable since that solved the issue in other similar questions, but I tried other cables and the problem persists and as I said, I had 1gbps connection before I sent my laptop to service with the very same cable I use now.

Comment: Hello, I just want my NIC to be able to go up to 1000 mbps since it is my internet speed, but it won't go upper than 100 mbps for some reason. I just want to know if I should send the laptop back to service or there are some faster options I have regarding the problem.

Comment: Have you tested it connected to different known working gigabit switch ports with different known working patch cords and checked the settings in adapter? If yes to all of those, send it back, if no, then check all those things first.

Comment: yeah, I did all that, and as I said, the setup is the same from before I sent the laptop to service. I guess there is no possibility of fixing it without touching the hardware then right?

Comment: Changing entire motherboard is common, so they could give you one with only 100 mbps NIC, it's more likely if the laptop model is older. Perhaps check the exact NIC model in Windows? If it even supports 1 gbps...

Comment: the laptop model i quite new, it's a gaming asus rog with gen 6 cpu. I checked under ethernet properties and at speed and duplex it is selected 1.0 gbps full duplex, so the NIC is compatible. It just doesn't want to work properly.

Comment: Please add the output of `wmic baseboard get product,manufacturer,version` to your question. You enter that at cmd.

Comment: My first instinct is simply that the drivers aren't configured for it. On Linux driver modules get loaded in order of the pci ids for which provide support.. on windows WHO KNOWS XD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek NIC running at 100Mb/s rather than 1000Mb/s](https://superuser.com/questions/57594/realtek-nic-running-at-100mb-s-rather-than-1000mb-s)

Comment: Cables, cable,s cables!  I have a bad cable right now doing the same thing; different hardware though.  I usually start with the cables, then move onto troubleshooting other stuff if the cable checks out.

Comment: Comments asked twice for the exact NIC model, but there is only the subject - not another screenshot. [ASUS specs](https://www.asus.com/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-GL752VW/specifications/) only says "RJ45 LAN Jack for LAN insert".
According to driver INF from ASUS a slow FE chip may be possible, although not likely:  
; Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller  
; Realtek PCI GBE Family Controller

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues. I tried to connect PC to a modem and got 1 Gbps. Connecting through a router (tried 2 different kinds of routers) and got only 100 Mbps. With all the plugging in and out, the PC suddenly registered 1 Gbps. So to anyone who is going through this. I really suggest not only swapping cables but plugging in-out a few times. Make sure there is no dirt etc. in the socket. Cables that consistently gave me 100 Mbps suddenly gave me 1 Gbps. also, I had a situation where a particular cable went from 1 Gbps to suddenly drop to 100 Mbps...